# Trouble selecting entire day from DateTime object in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am having trouble selecting an entire day from a DateTime column in my DataFrame.

I originally started with the date and time in separate columns, and it was a simple thing to select all rows containing a specific date. One DateTime column seemed more convenient, but I have not been able to find out how to select all entries for a specific date. When I don't specify a time, I get an empty DataFrame.

```
#minimal example
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':['2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:30:00', '2019-01-01 01:00:00']})
```

I can select specific times no problem:

```
df[df.date_time == '2019-01-01 00:00:00']
```

But this gives an empty DataFrame:

```
df[df.date_time == '2019-01-01']
```

What I want it to return is every entry that has the specified date, regardless of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your df has date_time as 'object'. You should first convert it to 'date_time' with

```
df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
```

This will do the trick. If you try now:

```
df[df.date_time == '2019-01-01']
```

you'll get your desired result (you will; note 2 records because they both comes at 00:00):

```
date_time
0   2019-01-01
1   2019-01-01
```

However, if you want to completely ignore the time, you should add this:

```
df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'].dt.date)
df[df.date == '2019-01-01']
```

to make sure your time is out and only then do:

```
df[df.date == '2019-01-01']
```

and the desired result:

```
    date_time   date
0   2019-01-01  2019-01-01
1   2019-01-01  2019-01-01
2   2019-01-01  2019-01-01
3   2019-01-01  2019-01-01
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First convert datetime into date
2. Then convert it in string

```
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time']).dt.date.astype(str)
df[df['date_time'] == '2019-01-01']
```